# Manipulate models from index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I'm working on a rails app which needs to implement product management.
The admin interface should allow to add new products to the system.
The index shows a list of existing products, and should allow batch editing of existing models (changing multiple products names, deleting multiple products via checkboxes etc).

**Issues**
I'm trying to figure out how to make the index page behave like a form. Currently I implemented the ability to delete multiple products using checkboxes:

- **index.html.erb**

  ```
  # The form_tag wraps the entire collection, with a path to delete multiple  
  # products defined in the controller/routes
  <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_admin_products_path, method: :delete do %>  

    # render the products collection:
    <% @products.each do |product| %>  
      # checkbox to mark product for deletion:
      <%= check_box_tag "products[]", product.id %>
      # content
      <%= text_field_tag "", product.name %>
      ...
  ```
- **products_controller.rb**

  ```
  # admin/products#index
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
  # admin/products#destroy_multiple
  def destroy_multiple
    Product.destroy(params[:products])
    redirect_to admin_products_path
  end
  ```
- **routes.rb**

  ```
  root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'home'

  namespace :admin do
    resources :products, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create, :index] do
      collection do
        delete 'destroy_multiple'
      end
    end
  end
  ```

As shown above, the form_tag in the view is set with the delete_multiple path.
When the submit button is pressed, all selected products are deleted.
The thing is, I'm rather clueless as how to implement the "update selected" button which will update selected products with the values in the various fields (most of which have been redacted for brevity).

Comment: You probably wanna have a look at active_admin or rails_admin

Comment: This isn't viable for this specific project, because I need to adapt an existing design, and from what I've learned thus far it would take a considerable amount of effort to mold active_admin to said design. Also note that being a new rails developer I rather get my hands dirty as much as possible for the time being, relaying on the least amount of rails "magic" until I catch the drift of how everything works :-)